# I want to put image title above the inserted image

Tags: troubleshooting

First of all, I apologize for my English, because my English isn't good.

I want to automatically put image title(not caption) above the inserted image in content area.

Like this:

< h3 >Image Title< /h3 >
< img src="abc.jpg" >

How do i make it?

OR

How can i call image title variable in wp-includes/media.php file?

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to achive these.
If you know php than you can do regular expression to find in text images and insert title before theme , but you need to write it somewhere to pull from like `<img src=".." title="My title" />` and then in php find , take title="" and insert before image in `the_content` filter for ex.
Seccond way is preaty much like first ( you need to write title="My title" ), but insted of php use jquery on frontend, for ex. u have container for content `.conteiner` then u do next
`$( '.conteiner img' ).each( function() { $(this).insertBefore( '<h3>' + $(this).attr( 'title' ) + '</h3>' ); } ):`